# Published website ASP.NET with IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I have just completed my website and I started working with IIS it works fine when I put all my file without published. I copy the whole website to wwwroot inside my folder as I said It works fine but when I tried to work without code behind page it didn't work I published website from VS. and I copy my published file to the same folder but it doesn't work.

I received this error:

```
Eval is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

I don't want to put my code behind page. How can I run my published pages?

Comment: Have you copied binaries in Bin folder?

Answer (score 0):

First, when you publish your web project, their are no code behind pages.
Do this, set a directory and publish your site in it.
Now cmd-> intemgr->

site-> -> add web site->

give site name and select an application pool, then set the physical path to the directory where your application is published, if necessary change the port to something like 50 because 80 is a standard port for http. Hit ok. Your site is ready.

Please check in application pool that your application pool is set to .Net framework version V4.0 (i mean the version compatible to your app ).

just click to browser the site, please do check the uri you can see the port number also